# Do I need to download all older SDKs?

Tags: android, sdk

Well, this is a silly question, but I was wondering whether we need to download all older android SDKs?

My targetSDk will will be 21 (android L), which is going to release tomorrow and my minSDK is 8 (android 2.2).

Do I need to download all other sdks that are in between these two?

Comment: Consider libraries that might have different min/target sdks set which are then required to build... I have all so I don't have to care...

Answer (score 0):

No, You do not need to download any older SDKs. It may be worthwhile to download an android system image for some older versions, and test your app on them in the emulator, but there is no need for the older SDK.

Answer (score 0):

No you most certainly do not need to download all SDK's.
For more reference check this question - [Which Android platform SDK do I need?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988189/which-android-platform-sdk-do-i-need)